# How to loop jQuery parsing with $().find() in depth of more than 2

Tags: jquery, xml, loops, parsing, find

I am trying to parsing XML data. And successfully, It worked. However, the result is very mixed because loop doesn't work properly.

My problem is I don't know how to loop in a specific tag. For example,

```
<item>  
    <word>aaa</word>
    <sup_no>0</sup_no>
    <pos>nnn</pos>
    <sense>
        <sense_order>1</sense_order>
        <definition>xxx</definition>            
        <translation>
            <trans_lang>xxx</trans_lang>
            <trans_word>xxx</trans_word>
            <trans_dfn>xxx</trans_dfn>
        </translation>
    </sense>
    <sense>
        <sense_order>2</sense_order>
        <definition>yyy</definition>            
        <translation>
            <trans_lang>yyy</trans_lang>
            <trans_word>yyy</trans_word>
            <trans_dfn>yyy</trans_dfn>
        </translation>
    </sense>
</item>
<item>
    <word>aaa</word>
    <sup_no>0</sup_no>
    <pos>nnn</pos>
    <sense>
        <sense_order>1</sense_order>
        <definition>xxx</definition>            
        <translation>
            <trans_lang>xxx</trans_lang>
            <trans_word>xxx</trans_word>
            <trans_dfn>xxx</trans_dfn>
        </translation>
    </sense>
    <sense>
        <sense_order>2</sense_order>
        <definition>yyy</definition>            
        <translation>
            <trans_lang>yyy</trans_lang>
            <trans_word>yyy</trans_word>
            <trans_dfn>yyy</trans_dfn>
        </translation>
    </sense>
    <sense>
        <sense_order>3</sense_order>
        <definition>zzz</definition>            
        <translation>
            <trans_lang>zzz</trans_lang>
            <trans_word>zzz</trans_word>
            <trans_dfn>zzz</trans_dfn>
        </translation>
    </sense>
</item>
```

I use `$().each(function(){});` for the `item`. But, I use `$().find().text()` to get the data. And that's it. I have no idea how to loop inside of a specific. Like double loop or even triple loop if it is needed.

My javascript code is:

```
                $(obj).each(function(){
            result += ($(this).find("word").text()
            +"<span class='pos'>("+$(this).find("pos").text()+")</span> "
            +"<span>"+$(this).find("sense_order").text()+"</span> "
            +"<span>"+$(this).find("trans_word").text()+"</span>"
            +"<div>"+$(this).find("trans_dfn").text()+"</div><br>");
                });
```

It just prints in one way(Up to down). Could you explain how it works for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use another `each` loop for the nested element.

```
$(obj).each(function(){

  var senseResult = "";

  $(this).find("sense").each(function(){
    senseResult += "<div><span>"+$(this).find("sense_order").text()+"</span> "
                +"<span>"+$(this).find("trans_word").text()+"</span>"
                +"<div>"+$(this).find("trans_dfn").text()+"</div></div>";
  });

  result += $(this).find("word").text()
         +"<span class='pos'>("+$(this).find("pos").text()+")</span>"
         + senseResult
         + "<br/>";

});
```